# Stripe Payment in Rails only showing up in logs as v1/token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Building an application in rails that uses stripe for its payment/checkout system. I have the charges controller, new.html.erb and all the necessary gems in place but for some reason whenever I use my credit card to test stripe with a real payment (the charge is only $2 so it doesn't hurt to test) it appears in my logs as a v1/token rather than a v1/charge and does not appear in the payments section. I have researched extensively the conversion from token to charge and have found multiple answers pointing to the same solution (creating a begin method that turns tokens into charges which I have) but when implementing it doesn't work for me. this is my current charges controller:

```
require "stripe"

class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # this will remain empty unless you need to set some instance variables to pass on
  end

  def create

  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 200

  # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
  # See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
  Stripe.api_key = "pk_live_z....." //taken out for security reasons

  # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
  token = params[:stripeToken]

  # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
  begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => @amount, # amount in cents, again
      :currency => "usd",
      :source => token,
      :description => "Example charge"
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
end

end
```

Comment: You need to use your secret key (`sk_...`) to create charges, not your publishable key (`pk_...`). Aside from that, your code looks correct!

Comment: hey thanks for that help. I updated the pk to my sk but it still is doing the same thing. maybe my new.html.erb code would be helpful:<script>
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="pk_live_Ju6evW0MOkDt4x2hQL33oBMc"
  data-name="Demo Site"
  data-description="2 widgets ($2.00)"
  data-amount="200">
</script>


</body>

Answer (score 0):

your create method is not being called which executes the logic of payment.

Comment: How do you know that method is not called?